# Suppose $\alpha$ is a rational root of a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Prove $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ .

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Suppose $\alpha$ is a rational root of a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Prove $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ .

**attempt:**

Suppose $p(x)$ is monic. Then the leading coefficient $a_n = 1.$

Thus, $p(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ ...+ a_1x + a_0$. Then let $\alpha = r/s \in \mathbb{Q}$ be in the lowest term, that is $(r,s) = 1$. And assume $\alpha = r/s$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $r|a_0$ and $s|(a_n= 1)$.

Then since $\alpha $ is a root, we have :

$p(\alpha) = \alpha^n + a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+ ...+ a_1\alpha + a_0 = (r/s)^{n} + a_{n-1}(r/s)^{n-1}+ ...+ a_1(r/s) + a_0 = \frac{r^n}{s^n} + a_{n-1}\frac{r^{n-1}}{s^{n-1}} + ....+ a_1\frac{r}{s} + a_0 =  0$.

Then multiply both sides by $s^n$.

Thus $ s^np(\alpha) = s^n(\frac{r^n}{s^n} + a_{n-1}\frac{r^{n-1}}{s^{n-1}} + ....+ a_1\frac{r}{s} + a_0)  = r^n + a_{n-1}r^{n-1}s + ...+ a_1rs^{n-1} + a_0s^n = 0$.

But $(r,s) = 1$ , so $s = 1$. Thus, $s | a_n$ , so $\alpha $ is an integer.

Can someone please verify this? any better suggestion would help.
Thank you !

Comment: Multiply throughout by $s^n$ and conclude $\gcd(r, s) \neq 1$, a contradiction, unless $s=1$.

Comment: Also you have written $s|a_n$. If $a_n=1$, there are not many possibilities for $s$.

Comment: Well, it seems like you are assuming what you are trying to prove, roughly, when you say $s\mid a_n=1$. (Once you get that step, you could be done - if $s\mid 1$ then $r/s=r\cdot(1/s)$ is an integer. But I think you can't assume that theorem here.)

Comment: @Macavity Why is $\gcd(r,s)\ne 1$?

Comment: @JohnCataldo Because you've assumed that you expressed $\alpha$ as a fraction in *lowest terms* (which you can always do).

Comment: If $s$ divides the leading coefficient of 1, why doesn't that immediately imply that $s = \pm 1$ and therefore $\alpha = \pm r$ is an integer?

Answer (score 3):

There are two proofs in your write-up that are intermingled to make a confusing reading. All-in-all, all the necessary arguments are given and every single statement is correct, but the structure could be better.

In the first part you prove the claim in the task, you *use the rational root theorem* to find that $s=1$ and thus $α=r$ is an integer. At this point the claim has been proven. There is no need to later come back to it.

Then you have a second part that is not really cleanly separated from the first part where you *state and prove the rational root theorem* (specialized to $a_n=1$) in that $gcd(r,s)=1$ and
$$
a_nr^n+s(a_{n-1}r^{n-1}+...+a_1rs^{n-2}+a_0s^{n-1})=0
$$
implies $s|a_n$ and similarly $r|a_0$.

From your question it is not clear if that second part is necessary for your solution write-up. That depends on if the rational root theorem was previously provided in the lecture or otherwise assumed to be generally known.

---

It is a sometimes somewhat hard to apply advice to structure your text cleanly in *claims* (lemma, proposition) and *proofs* wherever possible, so that the text in-between is mostly historical remarks and motivation. This might give the text a rigid feel, but it is much easier for the reader to orient themselves in it.

Answer (score 3):

This is another proof using Ring theory and Field theory.

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic polymonial having $\alpha$ as a root.

Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an U.F.D., there is an monic irreducible polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ having $\alpha$ as a root ($p(x)$ is a factor of $f(x)$).

By Gauss's lemma, the polynomial $p(x)$ is also irreducible over the faction field $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. We have
$$\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x] / (p(x))$$
hence the degree of $p(x)$ is $1$ (since the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has degree $1$), so $p(x) = x - \alpha$, therefore $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do you mean Q[x]/(p(x)) instead of Z[x]/(p(x)) in the penultimate line?

Answer (score 1):

Given a monic polynomial $f(x) = x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x],$ we may consider $f(x)$ as a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x].$ Given that $\alpha$ is a rational root of $f(x),$ the Rational Roots Theorem implies that we have $\alpha = \frac{r}{s}$ for some integers $r$ and $s$ such that $\gcd(r,s) = 1,$ $r \,|\, a_0,$ and $s \,|\, 1.$ We must have therefore that $s = 1,$ from which it follows that $\alpha = r$ is an integer, as desired.

Comment: Why do you need the condition that gcd$(r, s) = 1$? Isn't it enough that $s$ divides 1, and therefore $s = \pm 1$, and thus $r$ is a root?

Comment: That is the content of the Rational Roots Theorem. Essentially, this says that the fraction $\frac r s$ has been reduced to lowest terms.