# Question about a comment on a different question. A rational root of a monic polynomial over $\Bbb Z[x]$ is an integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

[This questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534745/suppose-alpha-is-a-rational-root-of-a-monic-polynomial-in-mathbbzx-pr) contains a comment that states that $\gcd(r,s)\ne 1$ (which leads to a contradiction) where our rational root is $r/s$.

Why would that be true?

Comment: [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Write the equation as $-r^n=s(a_{n-1}r^{n-1}+a_{n-2}r^{n-2}s+...+a_0s^{n-1})$. Then a prime divisor of $s$ divides the righ-hand side, and therefore it must divide the left-hand side ($-r^n$), and therefore, it must divide $r$. This means that any prime divisor of $s$ also divides $r$. If $s\neq1$, then such prime divisors of $s$ exist. This would imply that $gcd(s,r)>1$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $s^n$ gives $$r^n + a_{n-1}r^{n-1}s + \dots+ a_1rs^{n-1} + a_0s^n = 0$$ and so $$r^n=-s(a_{n-1}r^{n-1}+\dots+a_1rs^{n-2}+a_0s^{n-1}).$$  Thus $s\mid r^n$, which implies any prime factor of $s$ is also a prime factor of $r$.  So, we conclude $\gcd(s,r)\neq 1$ unless $s$ has no prime factors.